# What is the relation between azure tenant and azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Usually the following is the flow:

Tenant (aka Azure AD) -> subscription -> resource group -> resource (VM, Az SQL, Disk, etc)

However the Azure DevOps is service that is not a resource. So what is the relation between azure tenant and azure devops? Does the organization (and projects) in azure devops reside under the azure tenant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is the relation between azure tenant and azure devops?

Relationship between Azure Tenant and Azure DevOps is similar to the relationship between an Azure Tenant and an Azure Subscription. An Azure Tenant is essentially an instance of Azure AD where you define your users. An Azure Subscription relies on an Azure Tenant for authenticating users accessing that Subscription.

Same is the deal with Azure DevOps. Azure DevOps relies on an Azure Tenant for authenticating users accessing the resources inside an instance of Azure DevOps.

You may find this link helpful in understanding the relationship between Azure AD and Azure Subscription: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory (same thing applies for Azure DevOps).

Comment: There is concept of `Organization` inside of Azure DevOps. Is that different to the Azure tenant? So are you saying that Azure DevOps is a service that is part of the tenant to which the creator of the Organization belongs to?, and that multiple Azure DevOps organizations can belong to the same tenant and not shared across tenants on the same azure?

Comment: Based on the information provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/create-organization?view=azure-devops), an Organization is not an Azure Tenant. It is basically a way to group your projects together. Based on my understanding, an Organization in Azure DevOps is equivalent of an Azure Subscription.

Comment: So Azure tenant (an instance of AD) has under it 1 or more subscription. Similarly, the Azure tenant has under it 1 or more DevOps Organizations.

Comment: So it's not "under" kind of relationship between an Azure Tenant and an Azure DevOps Organization. Essentially it is a "Many-to-One" kind of relationship between them where many Azure DevOps organizations can trust a single Azure Tenant for authentication purposes. Please see [this image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/media/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory/trust-relationship-azure-ad.png). HTH.